# member is a required arg that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem with my bot because I don't want to load certain variables that are specified. If you see any errors in the code, I'd be very grateful if you could help.

Error: discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.

Here is code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/") 


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("----------------------")
    print("Zalogowano jako:")
    print("Użytkownik: %s"%client.user.name)
    print("ID: %s"%client.user.id)
    print("----------------------")

@bot.command(name='tutorial', help='Tutorial')
async def tutorial(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    message = await ctx.send('flag_gb In which language do you want to receive the instructions?')
    message = await ctx.send('flag_gb W jakim języku chcesz otrzymać instrukcje?')

    flag_pl = 'flag_pl'
    flag_gb = 'flag_gb'

    await message.add_reaction(flag_pl)
    await message.add_reaction(flag_gb)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(
            reaction.emoji) in [flag_pl, flag_gb]

    member = ctx.author

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=10.0, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == flag_pl:
                em = discord.Embed(tittle = "flag_pl", description = "**1**")
                em.add_field(name = "Opcja 1", value = "Link" );
                await member.send(embed=em)  

            if str(reaction.emoji) == flag_gb:
                em = discord.Embed(tittle = "flag_gb", description = "**2**")
                em.add_field(name = "Opcja 2", value = "Link" );
                await member.send(embed=em)
        except:
            print("Wystapil blad!")
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing` means that you have to put the name of the member after the command (e.g. `/tutorial user123` instead of `/tutorial @user123`). Also, an error you made is in

```
flag_pl = 'flag_pl'
```

and

```
flag_gb = 'flag_gb'
```

The emojis in discord **always** begin and end with :, so it should be

```
flag_gb = ':flag_gb:'
```

and

```
flag_pl = ':flag_pl:'
```